# Ruby Directory Glob Recursive on Absolute Path

Tags: ruby, directory, glob

I'm trying to get the Dir.glob of an absolute path:

```
path = "/Users/ken/templates"
scaffold = Dir.glob("#{path}/*.erb", File::FNM_DOTMATCH)
p scaffold.inspect
```

This is my directory structure:

```
/Users/ken/templates/test.erb
/Users/ken/templates/test2.erb
/Users/ken/templates/app/one.erb
/Users/ken/templates/app/two.erb
```

When I run on the directory I only get the files in the root of the directory:

```
"[\"/Users/ken/farmstead/test.erb\", \"/Users/ken/farmstead/test2.erb\"]"
```

But no entries for the app subdirectory.

How do I get the Glob to go recursive on the absolute path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get into subdirectories, one needs to instruct [`Dir#glob`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Dir.html#method-c-glob) to get into subdirectories:

```
#                            ⇓⇓⇓
scaffold = Dir.glob("#{path}/**/*.erb", File::FNM_DOTMATCH)
```

Quote from the documentation I linked:

> ******
>       Matches directories recursively.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that the / separation was for directories and files.

Comment: Excuse me? `/` is indeed a path separator.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way to tell glob about the absolute directory is to use the `base` parameter like so:

```
Dir.glob("**/*.erb", base: path)
```

Source: https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob